# Small Show/Hide JQuery Code Slows Site Considerably. Can It Be Written More Efficiently?

Tags: jquery

I am a novice who ...admittedly jumped headfirst into jQuery before coming to the understanding that jQuery's cross browser functionality is no longer as necessary as it once was. I've read that vanilla javascript can operate faster and I do appreciate that it does not require the additional server request for a library in the way that jQuery does. I am using wordpress as the CMS so I began with jQuery because it was already present and enqueued.

However, currently... I have the following code in a file called app.js that manages show / hide functions when a user interacts with a navigation bar.

I want to speed up my site and I notice that simply dequeuing the following code (app.js) decreases my page load speed dramatically.

- All files are concatenated in the end so the additional http request is not the source of the slowdown.
- The file size of app.js is not significant so I find it difficult to believe that it is responsible for the slowdown.

I am assuming that the slowdown is due to inefficient novice code structure.

Can the following code be rewritten to perform better?

TL;DR
With the following code included in the site the page speed fluctuates between 1.2s and 1.7s.
Without the code the page speed fluctuates between 0.5s and 0.9s

I definitely want the faster page speeds, but I'd like to keep the javascripting/jQuery functionality.

I am seeking insights and recommendations.

```
    // NAVIGATION BLOCK

    // NAV TO HOME SPLASH
    $("#navSHome a").click(function() {
            $("#pageAppeal").show();
        $("#pageBenefits").hide();
        $("#pageFeatures").hide();
        $("#pageEnthusiaCompare").hide();
        $("#pageAdChange").hide();
        $("#adContent1").hide();
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
        $("#siteMap").addClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Click Splash Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });

// NAV TO HOME BENEFITS
    $("#navHBenefits a").click(function() {
            $("#pageAppeal").hide();
        $("#pageBenefits").show();
        $("#pageFeatures").hide();
        $("#pageEnthusiaCompare").hide();
        $("#pageAdChange").show();
        $("#adContent1").show();
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
        $("#siteMap").addClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Click Benefits Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });



    // NAV TO HOME FEATURES
    $("#navHFeatures a").click(function() {
            $("#pageAppeal").hide();
        $("#pageBenefits").hide();
        $("#pageFeatures").show();
        $("#pageEnthusiaCompare").hide();
        $("#pageAdBreak").show();
        $("#adContent1").show();
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
        $("#siteMap").addClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Click Features Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });


    // NAV TO CASE STUDIES PAGE
    $("#navHWorks a").click(function() {
            $("#pageAppeal").hide();
        $("#pageBenefits").hide();
        $("#pageFeatures").hide();
        $("#pageEnthusiaCompare").show();
        $("#pageAdBreak").show();
        $("#adContent1").show();
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
        $("#siteMap").addClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Click Services Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });



    // OPEN PAGE MENU
    $("#navMenuOpenHome a, #iPhoneMenu a, .menu-item-185 a, .menu-item-626 a").click(function() {
            $("#pageMenuHome").toggleClass("On");
            $(".hamburger, .hamburger2").toggleClass("is-active");
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        $("#siteMap").toggleClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Open Menu Successful!" );
        });

    // Close PAGE MENU
    $(".navMenuItems a").click(function() {
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger, .hamburger2").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#siteMap").addClass("Right");
        $("#siteMap").removeClass("On");
        console.log( "Close Menu Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });


    // OPEN / CLOSE SITEMAP
    $("#siteMapBtn a").click(function() {
            $("#siteMap").toggleClass("On");
        console.log( "Open / Close SiteMap Successful!" );
        });


    // OPEN CONTACT FORM
    $("#navOpenContact a, #passFullSitePrice, #passSinglePagePrice, #passAddOnPrice").click(function() {
            $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
        $("#pageContactForm").addClass("On");
        console.log( "Open Contact Successful!" );
        });

    // Close CONTACT FORM
    $("#navCloseContact a").click(function() {
        $("#pageContactForm").removeClass("On");
        $("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
        $("#genericContactForm").show();
        $("#dynamicPricingForm").hide();
        console.log( "Close Contact Successful!" );
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        });

    // END NAVIGATION BLOCK
```

Comment: I do not see anything in there that should affect page load speed significantly.  Try removing the contents of app.js so that it is a 0 byte file and retest your page load speed tests again.  It is possible that the mere trying to load the script file could impact page speed performance regardless of the size or the content of the file.  If you find it is still slow, look into loading the script in a more optimized manner.

Comment: OK, I will try this. Thank you and I will report back.